# VBA - Modify sheet naming from source file

Tags: regex, vba, excel

I received help in the [past](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47514077/vba-rename-worksheet-after-source-file) for an issue regarding grabbing a source file name and naming a newly created worksheet the date from said source file name, i.e. `"010117Siemens Hot - Cold Report.xls"` and outputting `"010117"`.

However the code only works for file names with this exact format, for example, file named `"Siemens Hot - Cold Report 010117.xls"`, an error occurs because the newly created sheet does not find the date in the source file.

**CODE**

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim n As Double
Dim wksNew As Excel.Worksheet
Dim src As Workbook
Set src = Workbooks.Open(filePath, False, False)

Dim srcRng As Range
With src.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set srcRng = .Range(.Range("A1"), .Range("A1").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))
End With

With ThisWorkbook
    Set wksNew = .Worksheets.Add(After:=.Worksheets(.Sheets.Count))
    n = .Sheets.Count
    .Worksheets(n).Range("A1").Resize(srcRng.Rows.Count, srcRng.Columns.Count).Value = srcRng.Value
End With

' ======= get the digits part from src.Name using a RegEx object =====
' RegEx variables
Dim Reg As Object
Dim RegMatches As Variant

Set Reg = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
With Reg
    .Global = True
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .Pattern = "\d{0,9}" ' Match any set of 0 to 9 digits
End With

Set RegMatches = Reg.Execute(src.Name)
On Error GoTo CloseIt
If RegMatches.Count >= 1 Then ' make sure there is at least 1 match
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(n).Name = RegMatches(0) ' rename "Sheet2" to the numeric part of the filename
End If

src.Close False
Set src = Nothing
```

So, my question is, how can I get my code to recognize the string of digits no matter its position in the file name?

Comment: Is it safe to say that *any digit* found in the string should be pulled out? Or would you have, say, `123 Hot - Cold Report 010117.xls` and only want `010117`?

Comment: @BruceWayne Sometimes it will say `"Siemensx3A"`,  I am not sure if that's helpful or not to answer your question

Comment: What about `^\d{0,9}\B|\b\d{0,9}(?=\.)`?

Comment: @ACohen Someone asked but deleted their question, but is it always 6 digits long?

Comment: @dwirony - Yes they are all 6 digits

Comment: @ctwheels - That did not work, thanks though

Comment: Can you give some examples of strings that have the 6 digits you want **and** other misc. digits? We need to determine the pattern or logic in knowing how to pull out what number from a string.  Could you ever have say `Siemensx123456 Hot - Cold 010117.xls`, where you want `010117`?

Comment: @BruceWayne - I do not beleive I would ever have a file with the name `"Siemensx123456 Hot - Cold 010117.xls"`

Comment: @ACohen see my answer below showing how you can implement the regex I describe above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Code

```
^\d{0,9}\B|\b\d{0,9}(?=\.)
```

#### Usage

I decided to make a function that can be called inside a cell as such: `=GetMyNum(x)` where `x` is a pointer to a cell (i.e. `A1`).

To get the code below to work:

1. Open Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications (`ALT` + `F11`)
2. Insert a new module (right click in the Project Pane and select `Insert` -> `Module`).
3. Click `Tools` -> `References` and find `Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5`, enable it and click `OK`

Now copy/paste the following code into the new module:

```
Option Explicit

Function GetMyNum(Myrange As Range) As String
    Dim regEx As New RegExp
    Dim strPattern As String
    Dim strInput As String
    Dim strReplace As String
    Dim strOutput As String
    Dim match As Object

    strPattern = "^\d{0,9}\B|\b\d{0,9}(?=\.)"

    If strPattern <> "" Then
        strInput = Myrange.Value

        With regEx
            .Global = True
            .MultiLine = True
            .IgnoreCase = False
            .Pattern = strPattern
        End With

        If regEx.test(strInput) Then
            Set match = regEx.Execute(strInput)
            GetMyNum = match.Item(0)
        Else
            GetMyNum = ""
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

---

### Results

#### Input

- `A1`: `Siemens Hot - Cold Report 010117.xls`
- `A2`: `010117Siemens Hot - Cold Report.xls`
- `B1`: `=GetMyNum(A1)`
- `B2`: `=GetMyNum(A1)`

#### Output

```
010117        # Contents of B1
010117        # Contents of B2
```

[image: Snapshot of Excel]

---

### Explanation

I will explain each regex option separately. You can reorder the options in terms of importance in such a way that the most important option is first and least important is last.

- `^\d{0,9}\B` Match the following

  - `^` Assert position at the start of the line
  - `\d{0,9}` Match any digit 0-9 times
  - `\B` Ensure position does not match where a word boundary matches (this is used but may be dropped depending on usage - I added it because it seems the number you're trying to get is immediately followed by a word character and not followed by a space - if that's not always the case just remove this token)
- `\b\d{0,9}(?=\.)` Match the following

  - `\b` Assert position as a word boundary
  - `\d{0,9}` Match any digit 0-9 times
  - `(?=\.)` Positive lookahead ensuring a literal dot `.` follows

Comment: How would this handle something like `Siemensx333A Hot - Cold Report 010117.xls` or say `01182 Siemens3A Hot - Cold 010117`?

Comment: @BruceWayne the first example would yield `010117` whilst the second would yield `01182`. The OP would need to order the regex options in terms of importance. So if `010117` is the answer sought after for the second example, reversing the options such that `\b\d{0,9}(?=\.)|^\d{0,9}\B` is used instead will get the OP the appropriate value.

Comment: I am working on implementing it into the rest of my code.  How do I go about calling your module of code into the rest of it?  Is it, `Application.Run "Module4.GetMyNum"` ?

Comment: @ACohen I just made a module for ease of use. You would copy the contents of the function to a sub and then call the sub instead.

Comment: I inserted your code into mine and for some reason there is an issue with `Dim regEx as New regExp`.  Where an error occurs and says:  `"Compile error: User-defined type not defined"`

Comment: @ACohen you need to complete step 3 and add the `Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5` reference

Comment: Okay, and now it says `"Type Mismatch"`

Comment: My mistake, I added `.Object` to the end of it.  I removed that and it is working fine!  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Just my alternative solution to RegEx :)

This finds the first occurence of 6 consecutive digits, omitting blanks and periods... although there are probably some more issues with using `IsNumeric` as I believe a lowercase `e` is considered acceptable by it...

```
Sub FindTheNumber()

For i = 1 To Len(Range("A1").Value)
    If IsNumeric(Mid(Range("A1").Value, i, 6)) = True And InStr(Mid(Range("A1").Value, i, 6), " ") = 0 And InStr(Mid(Range("A1").Value, i, 6), ".") = 0 Then
        MyNumber = Mid(Range("A1").Value, i, 6)
        Debug.Print MyNumber
        Exit For
    End If
Next i

For i = 1 To Len(Range("A2").Value)
    If IsNumeric(Mid(Range("A2").Value, i, 6)) = True And InStr(Mid(Range("A2").Value, i, 6), " ") = 0 And InStr(Mid(Range("A2").Value, i, 6), ".") = 0 Then
        MyNumber = Mid(Range("A2").Value, i, 6)
        Debug.Print MyNumber
        Exit For
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Examples:

[image]

Immediate window:

[image]